# apply a boolean operator among all elements of an array

Tags: python, numpy, boolean

Is there a practical way to apply the same boolean operator (say `or`) to all elements of an array without using a `for` loop ?

I will clarify what I need with an example:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,1]])
b=a[0] | a[1] | a[2]
print b
```

What is the synthetic way to apply the `or` boolean operator to all arrays of a matrix as I have done above?

Comment: what do mean by `synthetic`?

Comment: I basically mean without a `for` loop. I wonder whether there is a numpy function or something similar to just apply the `or` operator to all elements like I have just done manually.

Comment: `|` is only logical OR for boolean arrays. Your `b=a[0] | a[1] | a[2]` is doing bitwise ORs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to do this would be to apply `numpy.any` along an axis:

```
numpy.any(a, axis=0)
```

That said, there is also a way to do this through the operator more directly. NumPy [ufuncs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html) have a `reduce` method that can be used to apply them along an axis of an array, or across all elements of an array. Using `numpy.logical_or.reduce`, we can express this as

```
numpy.logical_or.reduce(a, axis=0)
```

This doesn't come up much, because most ufuncs you'd want to call `reduce` on already have equivalent helper functions defined. `add` has `sum`, `multiply` has `prod`, `logical_and` has `all`, `logical_or` has `any`, `maximum` has `amax`, and `minimum` has `amin`.

Answer (score 1):

try either:

```
np.any(arr, axis=0)
```

or

```
np.apply_along_axis(any, 0, arr)
```

or if you want to use pandas for some reason,

```
df.any(axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` function for that:

```
from functools import reduce

a = np.array([[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,1]])
reduce(np.bitwise_or, a)
```

Comment: It is more efficient to use `ufunc.reduce`, i.e. `np.logical_or.reduce(a)` or `np.any(a,axis=0)`

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: I'm not a numby expert, so I am making an assumption below;

In your example, b is comparing the arrays with each other, so it is asking:

"Are there any items in a[0] OR any items in a[1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) OR any items in a[2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)"  is that your goal?  in which case, you could use [builtin any()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)

for example (changed numby to a simple list of lists):

```
a=[[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,1]]
b=any(a)
print b
```

b will be True

if however, you want to know if any element in it is true, so, for example, you want to know if a[0][0] OR a[0](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) | a[0](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) | a[1][0] | ...

you could use the [builtin map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) command, so something like:

```
a=[[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,1]]
b=any(map(any, a)
print b
```

b will still be True

**Note: below is based on looking at the NumPy docs, not actual experience.**

For NumPy, you could also use the [NumPy any()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.any.html#numpy.ndarray.any) option something like

```
a=np.array([[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,1]])
b=a.any()
print b
```

or, if your doing all numbers anyway, you could sum the array and see if it != 0